# Joining two tables | how to get the total sum

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

payments & payment_refunds

Multiple payments can have multiple refunds.

payments table
[image]

payment_refunds table
[image]

My Query:

```
with paymentsAggr as (
select p.invoice_id, sum(p.amount) as amount, sum(pr.amount) as amount2 from payments p
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id, SUM(amount)
    FROM
        payments
    GROUP BY id) AS payments_total ON p.id = payments_total.id
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        payment_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        payment_refunds AS pr
    GROUP BY payment_id) AS pr ON p.id = pr.payment_id
    group by p.invoice_id
)

select      
    SUM((qty * cost - cost * qty * discount_rate) * vat_rate) + SUM(cost * qty) - SUM(cost * qty * discount_rate) final,
    paymentsAggr.amount, paymentsAggr.amount2
from
invoices
        left join
    invoice_items ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id
    left join paymentsAggr on invoices.id = paymentsAggr.invoice_id
    group by paymentsAggr.invoice_id
```

Result:
[image]

Expectations:
I expected it to return a single row.
Basically sum of all 3 rows.

```
final | pAmount | prAmount
327.6     25       10
```

I've tried to sum the data twice and remove any ids from select which could be forcing the query to return multiple rows but that doesn't work.

Comment: Since you're using `GROUP BY` in the main query, you'll get a row for each invoice, not a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `GROUP BY paymentsAggr.invoice_id` in the main query, and sum `amount` and `amount2`. Then you'll get a single result that aggregates everything.

So change the main query to

```
select      
    SUM((qty * cost - cost * qty * discount_rate) * vat_rate) + SUM(cost * qty) - SUM(cost * qty * discount_rate) final,
    SUM(paymentsAggr.amount) AS pAmount, SUM(paymentsAggr.amount2) AS prAmount
from invoices
left join invoice_items ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id
left join paymentsAggr on invoices.id = paymentsAggr.invoice_id
```